# I have two flexboxes that occupy the same space but I want them to be next to one another

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am pretty new to HTML and CSS, and one of the things I have read is that you should keep your `<header>` and `<main>` tags separate.  When I do this, however, it makes it harder for me to align content on a page the way I want.  Currently I'm having issues with the content of the `main` overlapping with the content of the `header` elements, and they are both occupying the same space.  I tried setting the `:root` to `display: flex;`, and then `flex-direction: column;`, but this didn't seem to prevent the elements from overlapping.  I would like them to behave as if the header and main were both in the same flexbox and aligned in a single column, but so far I haven't seen anything addressing this issue.  I have attached a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/lumberjon1/pen/GRvxydB) link of what I have so far (the borders in the CSS were just to help me visualize where things were going wrong).

Answer (score 0):

After continuing to mess around with some of the values in the CSS selectors, I found that the one causing the issue was the position: fixed.  I knew that I wanted the nav-bar to remain at the top of the screen when scrolling, but I didn't fully understand the implications of having other elements in the same page as a fixed element, without using a relative parent.

When I used `position: fixed;` it caused that element to essentially be disregarded from the normal flow of the page, and other elements filled the top, making them appear stacked on top of one another.  In my particular case, I chose to go with `sticky` instead, as this accomplishes the same objective without complications.